# ASP.NET Core MVC add unique id to all razor html elements

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0

I am starting a new ASP.NET Core 6 MVC application, I need to be able to uniquely identify all html elements without inserting id attributes manually. I had a look at TagHelperComponenets but this provides html context as it is being render per request rather than on view compilation stage.

for example:
a razor file content is:

```
 <div>
        @for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
          <p>Hello world!...</p>
        }
</div>
```

I want it to be rendered as

```
<div id2="somerandomid1">
<p id2="somerandomid2">Hello world!...</p>
<p id2="somerandomid3">Hello world!...</p>
<p id2="somerandomid4">Hello world!...</p>
</div>
```

this would be global across the whole application and consistent between requests, ie: if I reload the page they have the same id2s.

I know I can do this manually but I want to be able to generate them and insert them automatically.

**Update:**
Looking closely at taghelper, I managed to create this global tag helper which adds the attribute id2, the problem found with it is that it generates the same uniqueid property for all elements within the for loop, kind of makes sense because it written as one tag within the for loop, although the process method gets invoked every time the tag is being rendered, how do I add generate an id2 now?

```
[HtmlTargetElement("*")]
public class GlobalTagHelper : TagHelper
{

    private static readonly string[] avoid = new string[]
    {
        "html",
        "link",
        "script",
        "head",
        "meta",
        "title",
    };

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {

        if (avoid.Contains(context.TagName))
        {
            return;
        }    
       
        output.Attributes.Add("id2", context.UniqueId);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Could you please share the code snippet what are you up to now.

Comment: Could you please explain how these `id2` would be generated? Not clear why the `div` and `<p>`  have the same `id2`?  It doesn't have the unique ids

Comment: they don't have the same id2, they should be different.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution.

this global tag helper will intercept every tag element while rendering views and partials, string[] avoid is used to skip elements that do not require identification, hashids library is used to convert an incremental id number into string of length 10.

the tag helper context provides a unique id that is unique to the element within razor, ie when the tag is looped it will have the same unique id, which makes the context unique but not the element itself, to solve this, a dictionary is used to id2sPerContext to record the number of repeating context unique id within the same httpContext, when it repeats a counter is incremented.

finally, a unique id (named id2) is generated by formatting the tag helper's unique id with an indexer integer, this string is now added to a static dictionary id2s, a global integer is incremented and then hashids library is used to generated a user friendly code.

Global Tag Helper Code:

```
[HtmlTargetElement("*")]
public class GlobalTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> id2s  = new();
    private static volatile int id2CountGen = 1;
    private static readonly  ConcurrentDictionary<HttpContext, ConcurrentDictionary<string, int>> id2sPerContext  = new();

    private const int Id2Length = 10;

    private static readonly string[] avoid = new string[]
    {
        "html",
        "link",
        "script",
        "head",
        "meta",
        "title",
    };

    private readonly HttpContext httpContext;
    private readonly IHashids hashids;

    public GlobalTagHelper(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        this.httpContext = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
        this.hashids = new Hashids(nameof(TestProject), Id2Length);
    }

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        if (avoid.Contains(context.TagName))
        {
            return;
        }

        var uniqueId = context.UniqueId;

        if (!id2sPerContext.TryGetValue(httpContext, out var counter))
        {
            counter = new();
            id2sPerContext.TryAdd(httpContext, counter);
        }

        counter.AddOrUpdate(uniqueId, _ => 1, (_, c) => c + 1);
        counter.TryGetValue(uniqueId, out var count);

        uniqueId += $"_{count}";

        if (!id2s.TryGetValue(uniqueId, out var id2))
        {
            id2 = GenerateNewId2();
            id2s.TryAdd(uniqueId, id2);
        }

        output.Attributes.Add("id2", id2);
    }

    private string GenerateNewId2()
    {
        var id = Interlocked.Increment(ref id2CountGen);
        return hashids.Encode(id);
    }
}
```

Concurrent dictionaries are used because as far as I know tag helpers are part of requests which is multithreaded, would be happy to test different solutions.